# Can't run Ubuntu using USB stick on Windows 8.1

Tags: boot, usb, windows

I have a USB drive (4gb) that I formatted to run Ubuntu on. I went to http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows and got PenDriveLinux installed. The USB has 2.2gb partitioned and everything looks well except for one thing: My computer refuses to run the USB drive!

I accessed my boot menu and there were about 5-6 different choices to boot from. I chose USB HDD but it loads up with a windows logo and I don't see ubuntu anywhere... Is my computer not able to run Ubuntu or am I doing something wrong? I've clicked on most of the USB options from the boot menu and I have not gotten anything different...

I am using windows 8.1 64-bit and I also installed ubuntu on 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to boot to your Ubuntu USB drive you will need to turn off the fast boot option.

Press the "super" key (Windows key) and then click the magnifying glass in the top right corner.

Enter "Control Panel". Click on the "Control Panel" option that appears.

When the "Control Panel" appears click on the "System and Security" heading..

For reference [here](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html)

Comment: I'll try to follow this! Will update on how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

I have a Dell Laptop with Windows 10 (upgraded from 8.1) installed on the HDD. I have a 32GB USB 3.0 Flash drive with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed (not Live).  In order to run it, I set my BIOS boot options to Fast Boot `Enabled`, Secure Boot `Enabled`, and I set my Boot Option Priorities as follows:

Boot Option #1 `[Windows Boot Manager]`
Boot Option #2 `[ubuntu]`

If I want to always default boot to the USB, I move `[ubuntu]` up to Boot Option #1.  It will work as long as I don't remove the USB while the computer is on.

When I want to boot to whatever is non-default, I press `F12` to enter the BIOS boot options and choose Windows or Ubuntu accordingly.

Also, when I boot to the USB drive, the GRUB has links to Ubuntu and Windows, so I can choose either from there.  If I forget and remove the USB while the computer is running or I don't have it in when I turn it on, I have to use the BIOS boot menu to access Ubuntu.  Otherwise, when I boot, I get the Grub and can choose, with Ubuntu being GRUB's default.

BTW, Ubuntu on the USB 3 boots faster than Windows 10 recovers from a Hibernate.

Edit:  My system operates with Fast Boot on in both the BIOS and Windows.  I generally hibernate windows when leaving and only shut it down when I am at home. Even if I shut it down, it comes up quickly.  Regardless, Ubuntu is faster.  :)